# Vim in Cygwin skips keypresses

Tags: bash, keyboard, vim, cygwin

My Cygwin installation works fine except when I code in vim, it skips the keys I press, and it happens annoyingly often. I don't seem to have this problem when I am in the bash, but when I start editing a file in vim, it becomes almost intolerable. 
I am using a remote windows 7 vm (I am not aware of the platform it runs on), but all the other functions work rather well).

Comment: What terminal do you use?

Comment: The one that comes by default in cygwin. I'm farely sure it's bash. When I run "echo $BASH_VERSION" it gives the following result: 4.3.42(4)-release

Comment: bash is a shell. I've asked you about terminal. [Terminal vs Shell](https://conemu.github.io/en/TerminalVsShell.html).

Comment: Ok, I have no idea what you are talking about. I would think that terminal is the application that lets you connect to the (usually) linux computer and it runs the shell. Example: getty, putty. In my case, I have cygwin which emulates the terminal... so... is the answer you want: cygwin?

Comment: OK, let me ask you slightly different: What do you start, what executable is contained in shortcut? Few terminal examples: iTerm2, konsole, guake, xterm, mintty.

Comment: Ok, so it's mintty.

Comment: Do you have latest cygwin updates? Try to rollback mintty or vim versions.

Comment: Just reinstalled the cygwin entirely. Works fine with no vimrc (i.e., pretty ugly, but fast). So, I'll see if one of vmrc settings causes my problem. Thanks for the advice!